# If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ $\lt$ $\infty$, $x_n$ must be $\lt$ $1$ for all $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$$x_n$ $\lt$ $\infty$,

does that mean that $x_n$ must be $\lt$ $1$ for all $n$?

Answer (score 4):

$$x_n = 2, 0,0 ,0, 0, 0\dots$$

Answer (score 4):

The other answers show that the claim is false.
However, it can be salvaged:

Since $x_n \to 0$, we have $x_n<1$ for all but finitely many $n$.

Answer (score 1):

For example:$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2}{n^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{3}\lt\infty$$
and the first term is $2$.
In general:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{k}{n^2}=\dfrac{k\pi^2}{6}\lt\infty$$
and many terms are greater than one